# Swift JSON Timing Issue creating Error Message

Tags: ios, json, xcode, urlsession

Upgraded to macOS 11.5 beta and started getting the following error messages from a JSON request.

```
 2021-06-08 11:17:31.819114+0100 Solar123[3066:1098095] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1.1 198.119.164.22:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2021-06-08 11:17:31.820015+0100 Solar123[3066:1098095] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1.1 198.119.164.22:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

The code triggering the errors is the URLSession part:

```
func calculateCloudCoverData(closure: () -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    self.semaphoreCloudCalculate.wait()
        self.getJson { newModel in
        self.globalNewModel = newModel
        self.updateUI(newModel: newModel)
        }
    self.semaphoreCloudCalculate.signal()
    }
}

func getJson(completion: @escaping (NewModel) -> Void) {
    // Assemble json request string
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let calenderLastYear = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    let calenderLastYearString = String(calenderLastYear-1)
    inputLatitude = GlobalVariables.latitudeSavedValue
    inputLongitude = GlobalVariables.longitudeSavedValue
    let latitudeString = String(format: "%.3f", GlobalVariables.latitudeSavedValue)
    let longitudeString = String(format: "%.3f", GlobalVariables.longitudeSavedValue)
    
    var jsonUrlString = "https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?request=execute&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=ALLSKY_SFC_SW_DWN&startDate="
    jsonUrlString = jsonUrlString + calenderLastYearString + "0101&endDate="
    jsonUrlString = jsonUrlString + calenderLastYearString + "1231&userCommunity=SSE&tempAverage=DAILY&outputList=JSON,ASCII&lat="
    jsonUrlString = jsonUrlString + latitudeString + "&lon=" + longitudeString
    jsonUrlString = jsonUrlString + "&user=anonymous"
    
    
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let newModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewModel.self, from: data)
            completion(newModel)
        } catch let jsonErr {
            let jsonErr1 = String(jsonErr.localizedDescription)
            // print("Unable to get data from NASA servers...", jsonErr)
            if jsonErr1.contains("The data couldn’t be read") {
             //   print("NASA Data Servers appear to be off line.")
            }
           //  print("Error serializing the NASA JSON data feed!", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Is this error erroneous or is there something I could do to make my code more watertight. It works and always has done. Any thoughts?

I changed the DispatchQueue from sync to async. Should it be async for a JSON request?

Comment: It isn't clear why you have the dispatch or the semaphore - You are immediately signalling the semaphore.  If your intent was to block the semaphore until the network operation is complete, you need to `signal` in the closure.  In answer to your question, it is probably just the random noise that Apple's code seems to emit at times that it really shouldn't.

Comment: What you are seeing is one snippet of six tasks that have to be executed in order. Left to their own devices they would return data all over the place. So each process is locked with semaphores - this might be overkill in this instance as you intimate.

Comment: It's not that it's necessarily overkill, I just don't think the code does what you want it to do. It won't block a second concurrent invocation of `getJson`

Comment: Thanks, removing that semaphore doesn't alter the working of the code :-) or the error message, unfortunately.

Comment: Just upgraded to MacOS 12 beta and the error messages have disappeared without a line of the code being touched. Your random noise theory would appear to be correct - many thanks.